# How to handle errors in res.render's callback

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out from the documentation how to properly deal with errors (such as a bad template) in the optional callback to `res.render` in Express.

I am calling it pretty much identically to the example in the docs and using it in certain situations to append extra data to the rendered output.

```
res.render('template', undefined, (err, html) => {
            if (err) // then what?
            var processed = process(html)
            res.send(processed)
        })
```

The [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) says:

> **callback**, a callback function. If provided, the method returns both the possible error and rendered string, but does not perform an automated response. When an error occurs, the method invokes next(err) internally.

But it seems like the only way to get proper behavior is if I can `next(err)` myself within the callback. Can someone tell me what the docs are trying to say here when they say next(err) will be called automatically?

Comment: That means that the error will propagate up the middleware stack until it is caught by the default error handler, which will log the error and send a generic error response to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Expressjs has a very good [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) on error handling. So, what you can do is throw an error if err exists:

```js
res.render('template', undefined, (err, html) => {
    if (err) throw new Error('Something went wrong in render');
    var processed = process(html)
    res.send(processed)
});
```

Then define a middleware that handles your error. You define it last after other app.use() and routes calls. A basic error handling middleware looks something like the following:

```js
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
});
```

It is imperative this middleware is error free. This is because this is the last bit of code that will catch any error that is passed down from the rest of your code defined above it.

Comment: I appreciate that and I use a similar method of catching errors. My question, however, is what is the documentation talking about when it says: 'When an error occurs, the method invokes next(err) internally.' This suggests that we shouldn't need to throw our own errors.